# Append to a (this) class

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

So I have code like this:

```
$(".list").append('<li>hi</li>');
```

Here's a working example: [http://jsfiddle.net/pXaSC](http://jsfiddle.net/pXaSC/)

When you click the `+` button, it adds a `button` to a `ul`.

If you copied and pasted the `.buttons` `div` (replicating the button and list) and clicked the `+` button on either of them, it would append a list item on both of them (http://jsfiddle.net/pXaSC/1/).

What I would like to achieve, however, is to make both lists work independently.

I know I need to use a `(this)` and `.parent()` selector somehow, but I just can't figure it out. **I do not want to use `id`'s.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event handler for the button click, `this` corresponds to the button. Therefore, you need to navigate a bit through the DOM tree to the desired `<ul class="list">`:

```
$(this).parent().find('ul.list').append(...);
```

One level up to the parent (the enclosing `<div>`), then find the `<ul>` inside that div.

http://jsfiddle.net/pXaSC/4/